# Novel / Book Object Oriented Design Approach

Tags: oop, design-patterns, data-modeling

I am creating an object oriented representation of a novel or book.  I am looking for design patterns or advice in terms of what to make an object, and what to make an attribute of another object.

For example, suppose I'm interested in the characters in the novel, and which chapters and pages they appear on.

The concept I'm struggling with is how to organize an object system with two types of "containers" that both participate in relationships with the same instances.  I imagine this comes up in other systems where there is a metaphorical "physical" and a "logical" view of the underlying data.

There are a variety possible objects here: Novel, Chapter, Page, Character.

There are a variety of relationships between these possible objects:

- Novels have a sequence of Chapters, a sequence of Pages, and a collection of Characters
- Chapters have a sequence of Pages, and a collection of zero or more Characters
- Pages are associated with one or more Chapters, and zero or more Characters
- Characters are associated with one or more Pages and Chapters

The purpose of these objects would be to answer questions like:

- What pages does character Alice appear on?
- What characters appear in chapter 6?
- Which characters frequently appear on the same pages?
- What page is character Bob mentioned for the first time on?

I'm a bit lost as to how to approach this sort of design.  I see a few approaches:

- Make everything (Novel, Chapter, Page, Character) an object, and each of these objects has lists of references to other objects they contain / relate to
- Give primacy to one or the other of Chapter or Page, and make the other an attribute of the first.  For example we could go with just a Novel, Chapter, and Character object list, and make "pages" an attribute of the Chapter object.
- We could take the above idea even further and just stick with Novel and Character, and give each Character a few attributes such as: "Occurs in Chapter" and "Occurs on Pages"

  Well, I hope that's clear enough for some OO design gurus to suggest where to draw the line between Object or Attribute, and how to design an object system where there are different kinds of containers (Chapter, Page) that the objects of interest (Character) belong to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is important that you have stated the purpose of your software will be to answer various questions about the book, including what characters appear on a given page.

This tells us two things:

1. You are seeking to model the physical layout of a particular
   edition of a book (since other wise the example question above would
   make no sense).
2. Your design is going to be heavily influenced by
   the scope of the questions that need to be answered, as this will
   determine whether your system will:

   - use data structures to pre-cache meta-data that will be required as answers (e.g.
     explicitly store a list of pages a character appears on),
   - store the "raw data" (e.g. as a tree of novel > chapters > pages > text) which is then processed to answer a given question,
   - some combination of both

I suspect that a combination is likely to be right in your case, so your "raw data" will be represented in similar fashion to the first approach you mention:

> Make everything (Novel, Chapter, Page, Character) an object, and each
>   of these objects has lists of references to other objects they contain
>   / relate to"

except that instances of `Page` would reference instances of `Text`, rather than `Character` which instead would become a meta-data class.

Meta-data could be pre-cached, or generated on demand by trawling the raw data.

Either way, you'll want to normalize your data model,